# Why won't rvm execute?

Tags: ruby

I installed RVM with gem install rvm.

```
gem list
```

shows rvm installed.

But when i type the command `rvm`, I get command not found. Where is the rvm bin?

Comment: have you reloaded the shell you were using ? Most of the time, new PATH parameter needs to be appended to current PATH to be able to find rvm by the system. Have you considered installing RVM from source rather than from gem because in the former you get the latest and greatest version of rvm !

Comment: I tend to symlink them into /usr/local/bin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would help to know which operating system you are using. On Debian and Ubuntu it seems to be `/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin`. But I guess a good way to find out would be to run `updatedb && locate bin/rvm`.